# Is Kyle Rittenhouse "out of the woods" or could he face Federal charges?

Tags: united-states, self-defense

Kyle Rittenhouse has been found not guilty of Wisconsin state criminal charges. Is there any federal law that he violated?

Comment: These questions are not particularly closely related.  Can you ask them separately?

Comment: @phoog  one question removed

Comment: There are so many Federal laws, no one is ever "out of the woods".  You're probably breaking more than one right now.

Comment: Consider that he killed two people. For most people, being responsible for the death of two people will cause them mental suffering for the rest of their life.

Answer (score 3):

Double jeopardy does not bar him from facing federal charges, although U.S. Justice Department policy reserves such prosecutions for exceptional cases. Also, it depends to some extent upon whether there is a suitable federal crime that fits the conduct.

Comment: "It depends to some extent upon whether there is a suitable federal crime that fits the conduct." I hope you arent implying a federal prosecutor would bring a case where there wasnt a suitable federal crime that fits the conduct.

Comment: it *also* doesn't stop his home state from filing suit for crimes he might have committed there.